# dataGridview comboColumn load data from sql Database

Tags: c#

I have TABLE1 with column name ITEM and i want to load item on ComboColumn of datagridview1.

please let me know how i can load data and select the required item name.
below is my connection string with database.

Comment: Please show us the code and the table definition.

Comment: You went to the wrong site if you wanted someone to write code for you or tutor you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction.

The following C# program retrieve the values from database and store it in a dataset and later bind to a combobox.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            int i = 0;
            string sql = null;
            connetionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            sql = "select au_id,au_lname from authors";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                adapter.Dispose();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
                comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "au_id";
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "au_lname";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.Text + " " + comboBox1.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
}
```